# How to simplify Sqrt[1/x] Sqrt[x]?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

In my expression, there appear terms of the form `A^(B Sqrt[1/C] Sqrt[C])`. *Mathematica* doesn't realize that this is just simply `A^B`. I tried telling it explicitly by some replacement rule. This works for simple cases, but somehow if the form above is embedded in a larger expression it does not do this replacement rule.

For example,

```
(9 + 9 E^((4 t Sqrt[Λ])/Sqrt[3]) - 
 12 y^2 Λ - 12 z^2 Λ + 
 6 y^2 Sqrt[1/Λ] Λ^(3/2) + 
 6 z^2 Sqrt[1/Λ] Λ^(3/2) + 
 x^4 Λ^2 + y^4 Λ^2 + 
 2 y^2 z^2 Λ^2 + z^4 Λ^2 + 
 2 x^2 Λ (-6 + 
    3 Sqrt[1/Λ]
      Sqrt[Λ] + (y^2 + z^2) Λ) + 
 6 E^((2 t Sqrt[Λ])/Sqrt[
  3]) (3 - 2 z^2 Λ + 
    x^2 (-2 + 
       Sqrt[1/Λ]
         Sqrt[Λ]) Λ + 
    y^2 (-2 + 
       Sqrt[1/Λ]
         Sqrt[Λ]) Λ + 
    z^2 Sqrt[1/Λ] Λ^(3/2)))/(9 + 
 9 E^((4 t Sqrt[Λ])/Sqrt[3]) - 
 12 y^2 Λ - 12 z^2 Λ + 
 6 y^2 Sqrt[1/Λ] Λ^(3/2) + 
 6 z^2 Sqrt[1/Λ] Λ^(3/2) + 
 x^4 Λ^2 + y^4 Λ^2 + 
 2 y^2 z^2 Λ^2 + z^4 Λ^2 + 
 2 x^2 Λ (-6 + 
    3 Sqrt[1/Λ]
      Sqrt[Λ] + (y^2 + z^2) Λ) - 
 6 E^((2 t Sqrt[Λ])/Sqrt[
  3]) (-3 + x^2 Sqrt[1/Λ] Λ^(3/2) + 
    y^2 Sqrt[1/Λ] Λ^(3/2) + 
    z^2 Sqrt[1/Λ] Λ^(3/2)))/. A_^(B_. Sqrt[1/Λ] Sqrt[Λ]) :> A^B
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: is this what you mean? `Assuming[x > 0, Simplify[Sqrt[1/x] Sqrt[x]]]` ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1txD.png) and `Assuming[x > 0, Simplify[A^(B*Sqrt[1/x] Sqrt[x])]]` gives $A^B$

Comment: `PowerExpand[A^(B Sqrt[1/C] Sqrt[C])]`..by default `M` takes in consideration Complex numbers too. On forcing assumption or `PowerExpand` it works without Complexes.

Answer (score 6):

That is only true if `C` (in your short example) is positive, therefore you must instruct *Mathematica* to make such assumptions:

```
FullSimplify[expr, Λ > 0]
```

> 1

You could also do this with [`$Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$Assumptions.html):

```
$Assumptions = {Λ > 0};

FullSimplify[expr]
```

> 1

[Blackbird](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1561/blackbird) suggests:

```
PowerExpand[expr] // FullSimplify
```

> 1

Where:

```
expr = (9 + 9 E^((4 t Sqrt[Λ])/Sqrt[3]) - 12 y^2 Λ - 
     12 z^2 Λ + 6 y^2 Sqrt[1/Λ] Λ^(3/2) + 
     6 z^2 Sqrt[1/Λ] Λ^(3/2) + x^4 Λ^2 + 
     y^4 Λ^2 + 2 y^2 z^2 Λ^2 + z^4 Λ^2 + 
     2 x^2 Λ (-6 + 
        3 Sqrt[1/Λ] Sqrt[Λ] + (y^2 + 
           z^2) Λ) + 
     6 E^((2 t Sqrt[Λ])/Sqrt[3]) (3 - 2 z^2 Λ + 
        x^2 (-2 + Sqrt[1/Λ] Sqrt[Λ]) Λ + 
        y^2 (-2 + Sqrt[1/Λ] Sqrt[Λ]) Λ + 
        z^2 Sqrt[1/Λ] Λ^(3/2)))/(9 + 
     9 E^((4 t Sqrt[Λ])/Sqrt[3]) - 12 y^2 Λ - 
     12 z^2 Λ + 6 y^2 Sqrt[1/Λ] Λ^(3/2) + 
     6 z^2 Sqrt[1/Λ] Λ^(3/2) + x^4 Λ^2 + 
     y^4 Λ^2 + 2 y^2 z^2 Λ^2 + z^4 Λ^2 + 
     2 x^2 Λ (-6 + 
        3 Sqrt[1/Λ] Sqrt[Λ] + (y^2 + 
           z^2) Λ) - 
     6 E^((2 t Sqrt[Λ])/Sqrt[3]) (-3 + 
        x^2 Sqrt[1/Λ] Λ^(3/2) + 
        y^2 Sqrt[1/Λ] Λ^(3/2) + 
        z^2 Sqrt[1/Λ] Λ^(3/2)));
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I also define $Lambda$ globally to be positive?

Comment: @user25477: question is..shall you ?

Comment: I want to... but how?

Comment: @user25477 See my update; use `$Assumptions`